# A monotone increasing function satisfying certain properties

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm wondering how to construct a function that is monotone increasing and bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ but discontinuous at every rational number. My hint was to list all of the rational numbers as $\mathbb{Q} = \{r_{1},r_{2},...\}$ and introduce a small jump discontinuity at each $r_{k}$.

I think the function may be a sum that doesn’t include the previous rational or sth (eg mb sth like $q_{n} <x$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{q_1,q_2,....\} $ an enumeration of the rationals.Take the function

$$f(x)=\sum_{q_n <x}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

The functions is clearly bounded and increasing by density of rationals.

Now let $q_N \in \Bbb{Q}$

Then, for all $x > q_N$, note that $$f(x) = \sum_{ x > q_n} \frac 1{n^2}  =  \sum_{ q_N > q_n} \frac 1{n^2} + \sum_{ x > q_n \geq q_N} \frac 1{n^2}$$ $$=f(q_N)+  \sum_{ x > q_n \geq q_N}\frac 1{n^2}$$ $$ \geq f(q_N) + \frac 1{N^2}$$

What does this tell you?

Comment: ok, so can you give some hints as to how to show formally that it is discontinuous at every rational number?

Comment: @fordjones i edited my answer..